# Non-response bias and margin of error for product feedback

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, error, bias, survey-sampling

If 1,000 people received a household product and later they were emailed a survey asking for their feedback, how would you avoid non-response bias? As an example, the survey would ask them to rate the product out of 5.

Surely, those that thought more positively about the product are also more likely to engage and respond to the survey. How would you account for this in the sample size and how would you calculate the confidence and error rate?

I have been using this as a guide: https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/sample-size-calculator/

In the example, would I need 906 responses to be 95% confident with a margin of error of 1%?